# Forward reference to enclosing class in optional return type, without typing.Optional?

Tags: python, python-typing

Python 3.10 introduced the `Foo | None` alternative type annotation syntax for `Optional[Foo]`. This doesn't seem to work when using forward reference to the enclosing type, like `'Foo' | None`, which instead results in a runtime error:

```py
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def maybe_create(arg: str) -> 'Foo' | None:
        if len(arg) < 5:
            return Foo()
        else:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(Foo.maybe_create(sys.argv[1]))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "staticmethod-test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo:
  File "staticmethod-test.py", line 3, in Foo
    def maybe_create(arg: str) -> 'Foo' | None:
                                  ~~~~~~^~~~~~
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'NoneType'
```

Using `typing.Optional` works as expected, like:

```py
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def maybe_create(arg: str) -> Optional['Foo']:
        if len(arg) < 5:
            return Foo()
        else:
            return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    print(Foo.maybe_create(sys.argv[1]))
```

Is there a way to express this optionality without extra imports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the union type contains forward references you have to wrap the entire return type in quotes.
Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#union-type),

> The `|` operand cannot be used at runtime to define unions where one or
> more members is a forward reference. For example, `int | "Foo"`, where
> "`Foo`" is a reference to a class not yet defined, will fail at runtime.
> **For unions which include forward references, present the whole
> expression as a string, e.g. `"int | Foo"`**.

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def maybe_create(arg: str) -> "Foo | None":
        if len(arg) < 5:
            return Foo()
        else:
            return None
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from `annotations` future-import mention (so that you can remove quotes entirely).